# Generating PDF for each feature in feature class based on attribute with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, pdf

I have a feature class of points that represent storm water inlets.  I am trying to automate a process that does the following.

1. finds all of the inlets that have a field called "Marker" populated with the string "No"
2. generate a PDF for each of these features that is a centered view at 1:50 scale.

I'm pretty new to Python.  I've been working on this for awhile and keep getting an output of a single PDF (not 800, which is the aprox. # of inlets with "No") and the ArcMap crashes as the script is finishing.  I'm sure my code is pretty whack!

[image]

Comment: This is an old question but, as I am confident you now know, questions about code should always have that presented as text rather than a picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the "SHAPE@" token with the search cursor, then do something like this:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("SHAPE@", "UNIQUE_ID")) as searchCur:
    for row in searchCur:
            myDF.extent = row[0].extent
            myDF.scale = 50
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(thisMap,    
                r"N:\27000s\27800\GIS\John_Working\PDF\Map_" + str(row[1]) + ".pdf", 
                 resolution=100, image_quality="Normal")
```

Comment: Thanks!  this works perfectly! If you don't mind... Could you elaborate on what I was doing wrong, why is the SHAPE@ token necessary?

Comment: If you are using Search Cursor DA, you do not need to also Select the features.  The cursor will go to every row in the "for row in searchCur" loop.  The SHAPE@ token returns the geometry of the object, so you can grab that extent and set it as the data frame extent (myDF.extent = row[0].extent), then set the scale, refresh and export the pdf.

Comment: That makes a great deal of sense. Thank you for the explanation!